# Where can I buy kosher ground beef in London?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, product-recommendation, travel, meat

I’m thinking ubiquitous companies like the big chains: e.g. Sainsbury's, Tesco, M&S, Waitrose, et cetera.

Or perhaps would it be better for me to ask on Travel Stack Exchange instead?

Comment: Certainly the dedicated kosher stores in Golders Green. I'd imagine the big chain locations that are near one or more of the synagogues. https://theus.org.uk/category/communities . If you know which neighborhood you have in mind, try contacting the local synagogue; they should know where to find kosher meat.

Comment: Just FYI in the UK "ground beef" is called "mince". You will only find it in the big kosher supermarkets and butchers. If you would like me to supply you a list of these - let me know...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a huge difference between USA/Israel vs. UK. In the USA, the OU are on top of their game. Most stores in the USA, even 1000 miles away from a Jewish hub, have plenty of OU goods on their shelves, with hechsherim. In the UK, you need to download/buy/look up the [KLBD Kosher guide](https://isitkosher.uk/), which lists things that are kosher. The vast majority of these things don't have any hechsher on the packet, so you are relying only on the guide.

Regarding meat, I've pretty much **only** seen that sold in Orthodox kosher stores/butchers, and rarely if ever in any big stores like Sainsbury's. Best head to London, Manchester or Gateshead to get hold of some!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the kosher kingdom in Golders Green https://kosherkingdom.co.uk/